# Add ability to Opt In / Invite Only Private Messaging

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It would be great if StackExchange had the ability for and Opt-In or invite based PM system. Especially for the exchanges dedicated to specific topics (i.e. Salesforce) Many times I have wanted to connect with people or send information on how to contact me to troubleshoot issues etc but there is really no current way to do it that is not public or requires one to sit in a chat room while waiting for the other to show up.

Ideally it would have thee following features:

1. The ability to send a PM to a user can only happen after the "Receiving" user has sent an invite to the "Sender" to connect
2. The "Receiving" user can revoke the invite at any time
3. No "Invite Request" feature will be present

Thoughts, comments?

Comment: Chat is very clunky for the back and forth required to pull extended discussions out of comments. I think this feature would go a long way to alleviating that.

Comment: I like this idea. Often I've wanted to connect with certain users here to further discuss a post, but this venue doesn't provide a means for that to occur.

Comment: I like this idea. I think this would replace one of the main reasons chat exists, and that would bring us one step closer to not needing SE chat at all.